# Class Member becomes undefined

Tags: class, typescript, undefined, typeerror, member

I am quite new to TypeScript and I experience a strange problem at the moment. I create an instance of my main class when the document is ready, using JQuery.

```
var main: MainApp;
$(document).ready(function () {
   main = new MainApp();
});
```

The simplified *MainApp* Class:

```
class MainApp {
   // Helper Objects
   net: AppNetworking;
   urlHelper: UrlHelper;
   cat: Category;

   // Construction
   constructor() {
      this.net = new AppNetworking();
      this.urlHelper = new UrlHelper();
   }

   // Ajax Callback with Data needed to initialize the "cat" object
   private AjaxCallback(categoryData){
      this.cat = new Category(categoryData);
   }

   // Event Handler for an HTML-Element
   // As it would be called anonymously in JS I decided to make it a static function
   static onClickSendButton(): void{
      // Using some members of the MainApp
      var hostUrl: string = main.urlHelper.getQueryStringParam("HostUrl");

      if (main.cat.isValidCategory()) {
         main.sendCategory();
      }
   }

   sendCategory(): boolean {
      // Some logic to send data via AJAX
   }
}
```

The function is being registered to the *onClick* Event of a Button on construction of the `MainApp` Class.

```
$("#btnSendCat").click(MainApp.onClickSendButton);
```

When the function `onClickSendButton()` gets called, it produces the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidCategory' of undefined
```

When debugging, the `urlHelper` Instance is defined, but the `cat` Instance is undefined. As I do not touch the instance `cat` anywhere in my application, I'm really confused how it is undefined. Also when checking the `main` variable all members are defined!

Am I doing anything illegal here? Could there be issues with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left some important parts of my App out, I'm sorry. Later in the project I used to reinitialize that Category Object. This re initialization was done in an AJAX-Callback Function. This function runs outside of my Object and `this` wont be my `MainApp` Class but the `Window`. I think it's what you call an *anonymous function* in JavaScript.

I fixed that issue by taking use of my global `main` Variable

```
class MainApp {
   // Called anonymous so it should be a static function
   private AjaxCallback(categoryData){
      // this.cat = new Category(categoryData);  ! this will be the Window Instance and not a MainApp Instance

      main.cat = new Category(categoryData); // Initialization using the "main" variable
   }
}
```

The call in my `onClickSendButton` Method to `this.cat` succeeds now, as this.cat was reinitialized correctly.

This video helped me a lot in my researches: [Understanding "this" in TypeScript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA)

Answer (score 2):

Completely revised answer. I actually answered with the two most common scenarios for this error, but actually your problem is different.

The usual answers are

1. Make sure you are referencing `.js` files, not `.ts` files
2. Make sure you are loading scripts in the correct order

In your case, this is not the problem and your code is sufficient to recreate the issue.

I have put together the following test, filling in the blanks - and it works as expected.

app.ts

```
declare var main: MainApp;

class AppNetworking {

}

class UrlHelper {
    getQueryStringParam(input: string) {
        console.log('Got here getQueryStringParam');
        return input;
    }
}

class Category {
    isValidCategory() {
        console.log('Got here isValidCategory');
        return true;
    }
}

class MainApp {
   // Helper Objects
   net: AppNetworking;
   urlHelper: UrlHelper;
   cat: Category;

   // Construction
   constructor() {
      this.net = new AppNetworking();
      this.cat = new Category();
      this.urlHelper = new UrlHelper();
   }

   // Event Handler for an HTML-Element
   // As it would be called anonymously in JS I decided to make it a static function
   static onClickSendButton(): void{
      // Using some members of the MainApp
      var hostUrl: string = main.urlHelper.getQueryStringParam("HostUrl");

      if (main.cat.isValidCategory()) {
         main.sendCategory();
      }
   }

   sendCategory(): boolean {
       // Some logic to send data via AJAX
       return true;
   }
}
```

index.html snip

```
<div id="btnSendCat">BTN SEND CAT</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var main;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        main = new MainApp();
        $("#btnSendCat").click(MainApp.onClickSendButton);
    });
</script>
```

The result of running this test is the following output in the console window:

```
"Got here getQueryStringParam" app.js:10
"Got here isValidCategory" app.js:19
```

Comment: You may have a point there, but that is not the source of the problem. "Also when checking the main variable all members are defined!". The method gets registered to the JQ Event Dispatcher while construction of the `MainApp` class!

Comment: Oh and the `main` Variable is defined otherwise I would get the TypeError when trying to read the property `cat` because `main` would be undefined.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You *probably* have a different problem to the usual two - although you haven't supplied a complete working example so I have had to extrapolate to show you a working version.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I will try to reproduce my error with the most simple example and will rework my question aswell, as its a little different.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, I could not reproduce the problem with an sample app. So I found out that the problem comes from an anonymous call to my function which resulted in `this` being the Window instance and not my App. Sorry for your time man :/